# Conflicting packages in presentation (beamer vs. ethiop)

Tags: beamer, packages, babel, languages

I'm making a presentation and I have to include some text in Ethiopic script. For documents, the ethiop-package is a great help, but when in beamer mode, I get an error:

> /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucsencs.def:16:
>   Undefined control sequence.
>   \eth@altchar #1->\def \eth@res 
>                                 {\eth@doaltchar {#1}}
>   l.16 ...2011/01/21 Fixes to fontencodings LGR, T3]

I think there is some conflict between beamer mode and the ethiop package. What should I do?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{ \usetheme{Warsaw}      
  \usecolortheme{default} 
  \usefonttheme{default}  
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ethiop}
\newcommand{\etp}{\selectlanguage{ethiop}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

{\etp 'ana negu'sa wa-'antemu 'agbertya .tabbabt}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

O, and this is my first presentation with LaTeX.

Comment: Avoid `utf8x` and use `utf8`.

Comment: Or load ucs through the documentclass `\documentclass[ucs]{beamer}`. (But I agree with egreg, that one should avoid it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package `ucs` and its `utf8x` option for `inputenc` are often cause for troubles and, in general, I don't recommend using them.

Your document compiles just fine if you change `utf8x` into `utf8`. However, I suggest not using `\selectlanguage`, but other features of `babel`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{ \usetheme{Warsaw}      
  \usecolortheme{default} 
  \usefonttheme{default}  
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]} 


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ethiop}
\newcommand{\textetp}[1]{\foreignlanguage{ethiop}{#1}}
\newenvironment{etp}
  {\begin{otherlanguage*}{ethiop}}
  {\end{otherlanguage*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\textetp{'ana negu'sa wa-'antemu 'agbertya .tabbabt}

\begin{etp}
'ana negu'sa wa-'antemu 'agbertya .tabbabt
\end{etp}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The two ways are essentially equivalent, but clearer.

[image]

As Ulrike Fischer remarks in a comment, you could also use `utf8x`, provided you pass the `ucs` option to the class:

```
\documentclass[ucs]{beamer}
```

otherwise the package is loaded too late. However, I don't think you need `utf8x`.